# powershell while loop not working as expected

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I'm having issue with this while loop. Even when the status is returned as online its still stuck in the while loop... any ideas would be amazing :)

```
$instance = "(opsworks instance id)"

$status = (Get-OPSInstance -InstanceId $instance  -Region eu-west-1).Status.Trim()
Write-Host "Initial:$status"

while($status -ne 'online' -or $status -ne 'start_failed')
{
  $status = (Get-OPSInstance -InstanceId $instance  -Region eu-west-1).Status.Trim()
  Write-Host "Next:$status!"
}
```

Comment: Change `-or` to `-and`; when it is 'online' it is also 'not start_failed' so the loop still loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a basic boolean algebra. It happens as `online` is not equal to `start_failed`. The `-or` operator will check both sides of the expression and will return `true` incase of either matches.

Condition

```
($status -ne 'online' -and $status -ne 'start_failed')
```

will be evaluated as `false` iff `$status` is neither `online` nor `start_failed`.

Comment: Thanks! I get what your saying now and totally see where I went wrong! Amazing and thank you :)